# Проводится ли поиск DNS при последующих загрузках страниц сайта?

Tags: dns, tracert, трассировка

Тестирую доступность сайта из различных точек мира. Обратил внимание, что значительный процент времени в общей длительности загрузки занимает поиск DNS.

Как понимаю, это происходит при первичном обращении к сайту из клиента, где не был закэширован нужный DNS. Будет ли при последующих загрузках страниц сайта проводится поиск DNS (как при первом заходе) или на его определение уже не будет тратиться время?

P.S. При повторном тестировании (через тот же сервис) вижу, что процент на поиск DNS значительно сократился, но хочу подтвердить мои предположения.

Comment: Вы же сами написали про DNS-кэш. Есть такая штука и она действительно может сокращать время резолва.

Answer (score 1):

Если не сильно углубляться в устройство DNS, то обязательно будет повторен процесс резолва по истечении времени жизни этой записи (TTL) в кэше DNS сервера.